# ease in from left to right Css3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've been searching for two hours trying to figure out how to make this transition happen? I've tried the code from W3 schools but it just made my Div bigger
http://themeforest.net/item/kappe-full-screen-portfolio-blog-wp-theme/full_screen_preview/6854128

This is what I have so far

```
 .nav{
width:20%;
position:fixed;
margin-right: 1.25%;
margin-left:1.55%;
background-color:white;
height:auto;
font-weight:bold;
box-shadow: 
            0px 11px 8px -10px #CCC,
            -15px -8px 8px -10px #CCC;
}
.nav li {
text-align:right;
}

nav li a{

background-color:white;
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
padding-right:5%;
display:inline-block;
padding-left:70%;
border-right: 1px dotted #DCDCDC;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #DCDCDC;
border-top: 1px dotted #DCDCDC;
font-size: 150%;
font-weight:300;
font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
-webkit-transition:width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition:width 2s;
}

.nav li:hover a
{
color:white;
background: #2876b2;
width:100%;
}
```

---

```
<div class="nav left" >

<nav >
<ul>
<li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>                          
</ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Can you give any HTML code related to this? You haven't even said which element you want to ease-in. Please give more info

Comment: I have a vertical navigation bar and I wanted to implement the same transition into my theme.
I added my Html and whole css nav

Comment: What transition? What should ease-in?

Comment: The li 
same as 
 http://themeforest.net/item/kappe-full-screen-portfolio-blog-wp-theme/full_screen_preview/6854128

Comment: Do you mean the li being colored blue or the submenu opening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/UhErG/

```
nav a span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

nav a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #1AB5B3;
    transition: right 250ms;
}

nav a:hover:after {
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You are the man !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
any books you recommend that I should read in regards to Html,css and web development. This is completely off topic and I'm trying to teach myself.

Comment: There are some handy things to know about CSS, one of those is using position absolute inside a position relative/absolute/fixed. Some great links: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/ , http://css-tricks.com/ , http://tympanus.net/codrops/ , http://adamschwartz.co/magic-of-css/ , http://flukeout.github.io/ , http://lea.verou.me/

Answer (score 1):

The 'transition' property in CSS can be very easily achieved using a LESS or SASS Mixin. If you are not familiar with using a CSS Preprocessor, I would recommend reading up on using a framework like LESS or SASS. They have made writing CSS much much easier for me.

LESS introduces all sorts of things, my favorite being the 'mixin'.

Here is a mixin example that takes care of your "ease in" desire.

```
/* Mixin */
  .transition (@prop: all, @time: 1s, @ease: linear) {
  -webkit-transition: @prop @time @ease;
  -moz-transition: @prop @time @ease;
  -o-transition: @prop @time @ease;
  -ms-transition: @prop @time @ease;
  transition: @prop @time @ease;
}





/* Example on how to use mixin with div */

#somediv {
    .transition(all, 0.5s, ease-in);
}
```

If this isn't exactly what you want, I am most positive you can achieve it through a less mixin of some sort. Hopefully I got you started in the right direction !

Comment: would I implement this exactly as written and I will read up on that someone in class mentioned it to me a a couple weeks ago.

Comment: not exactly as written, this is just an example on using a less mixin. Read up on using a CSS Preprocessor such as LESS here : [LESS Site](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: Hey @xJackk do you mind contacting me I'm trying to start with LESS but I have a few questions. I didn't see any contact info on your Stack profile. Please contact me at Paulbrunache@gmail.com I would really appreciate it.